# What if I override an instance of Task which is running?

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

I have a situation (right or wrong) where I might need to abandon a running instance of a Task and start a new one. Cancellation is not an option as this is pretty much legacy code which would take a huge effort in building in support for passing cancellation tokens. I mean something like this

```
public Task TaskUnderObservation{get; private set;}
public async Task WatchTaskInternal(Func<Task<TResult>> task)
{
    try
    {
        if (TaskUnderObservation != null) //basically if we are re-using this instance of class
            ResetCommonTaskState();
        TaskUnderObservation = task(); //Task is defined as a class level variable of type Task
        LogManager.Instance.Info(this, "Started Task");
        await Task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogManager.Instance.Error(this, "WatchTaskInternal Errored", ex);
    }


}
```

The question is what happens to the running TaskUnderObservation is the method WatchTaskInternal is called repeatedly something like this.

```
var x = new TaskWatcherClass();
x.WatchTaskInternal (//some Func);
x.WatchTaskInternal (//some other FUNC);
```

Would my running task be abandoned or ignored? If I had a WPF application which was binding to the result of my TaskUnderObservation object would it bind it to the result of the first invocation or the most recent one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't abandon running code. The running code must be complicit, and so support some kind of cancellation.

You can abandon the task by simply dropping the reference to it, but the code that is running will run to completion.

Don't be tempted to use `Thread.Abort`. It is pure evil.